# Delphi TAcroPDF - disable Save button, toolbar panel and rightclick popupmenu

Tags: delphi, pdf, adobe

I am working with strong restricted environment.
Application can show PDF files inside window, but I would like to disable some features:
- save button
- show toolbar Adobe Reader button
- right click mode
- use only hand tool

The PDF file should be only in ReadMode, with possibility to print.

I am used "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0" as parameter, but toolbars could be activated by right click.

Any ideas or other, more flexible and free library for PDF ?

Windows 7 x64,
Delphi Seattle
Adobe Reader XI

Comment: It can't be a very restricted environment if you can run acrobat reader in an ActiveX. That's as insecure as it gets. Further, why would the user need to save the PDF file. They can read it from the disk just as acrobat would

Comment: User can load PDF from database, and show it. User can print file, but should not save it. Application is started by remote desktop (RDP). User should not see the file system. There would be great if AcroPDF can load PDF from stream, but not. And AcroPDF can not load PDF directly from database, unless I could set header for session token, but I can't see that possibility.

Comment: If file system cannot be seen by user you can't load the pdf

Comment: I am asking how to disable some buttons, or all toolbar/navbar etc. permanently for user.

Comment: The file has to be stored on disk for the reader control to access it. The users can do so too. The control doesn't allow you to disable buttons. Are you prepared for the eventuality that what you seek to do is not possible?

Comment: Yes, I am prepared. Until I find good component, I will use Adobe ActiveX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer partly because there is more to say than will fit in a comment.

Firstly, iirc, the automation of Acrobat Reader was only ever intended to assist it being embedded in IE and, over the years, there have been some changes which were apparently intended to restrict other use (even supposing your current Reader licence permits it).

Anyway, in your position, I would implement the PDF functions by calls to the PdfTK utility

https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/

having checked its licence of course.

I've always found PdfTK to be ultra-reliable and it can do things that even the automation library of the full Acrobat cannot, like "flattening" PDF documents, properly embedding watermarks, etc.

Btw, PdfTK is a command-line utility and operates on files, so requires access to a file system, which may of course rule it out for your situation.